# use preference edittext except filename

Tags: android, preferences

I have application that searchs External storage for the file i want..Example for song named sound1.mp3 `String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), "sound1.mp3);` .I use loaded sound for soundpool. I want to get text from Preference Edittext and use it except "sound1.mp3".. I tried this :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("EditText",0);
            String zipStr = settings.getString("ime", "");   
        sp = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        String path = getFullFilePath(getApplicationContext(), zipStr);
        Log.d("ime", "Path: " + path);
        mSoundId = sp.load(path, 1);
```

LogCat gives this :

```
11-06 15:57:59.169: D/ime(5688): Path: /mnt/sdcard
11-06 15:57:59.539: E/SoundPool(5688): Unable to load sample: (null)
11-06 15:58:01.149: W/asset(5688): deep redirect failure from 0x0103003e => 0x02060007, defStyleAttr=0x00000000, defStyleRes=0x00000000, style=0x00000000
11-06 15:58:17.509: W/SoundPool(5688):   sample 1 not READY
```

Comment: could it be that you pc still got access to your sdcard?

Comment: No my pc doesn't have acces to sdcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you have stored in `zipStr` is, according to your LogCat, `/mnt/sdcard`

`SoundPool.load` requires the path to an audio file (see documentation: [SoundPool.load()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#load%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)).

make sure your `zipStr` is equal to something like `/mnt/sdcard/sound1.mp3`.

Comment: That would not work. All i want is to get text from zipStr and use it as filename

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. What you do now is use zipStr as a path (or file name). The problem is that the path stored in your `SharedPreferences` is not a path to an audio file. Can you please post the method `getFullFilePath`

Comment: It is used as filename  private String getFullFilePath(Context context, String filename) {

  File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  File file = new File(directory, filename);
  if (!file.canRead()) {
   // error handling
  }
  return file.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: Your `getFullFilePath` will return `/mnt/sdcard` if `filename` is an empty string. Meaning you do not have anything stored in your `settings.getString("ime", "");` and the default value `""` is returned. How do you put your filename into shared preferences?

Comment: You need to do the following when setting your filename: `SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences( "EditText",0); SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit(); editor.putString("ime","sound1.mp3"); editor.commit();` Make sure you remember the last `commit`, it is easy to forget ;)